# SCSS stylsheet is not applying to my React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, sass, styling

I have a react component called "header" which is going to be the header element on my webpage. Currently, all I have for the header component is:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import '../header/header.scss';
export default class Header extends React.Component {
render() {
 return <div className="alignment">Test</div>
}
}
```

and my stylesheet is also simple:

```
.alignment{
text-align: center;
```

}

I placed the header component on my main App.js page, but the text alignment isn't showing up. I used Chrome debugger tools, and it is not even showing up in the styling as a class. I'm not sure what else to do, maybe I'm missing an import somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure the relative path to your stylesheet is correct?

Comment: I m sure whether this is going to work, you should be building the sass file separately and add it to your index.html file, not in your js file.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do you use webpack? 2) If you use webpack, have you installed `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `style-loader`? Because if you do not use webpack, or you do use webpack but have not installed and configured the above three.. I do not think it's possible to use scss directly in your codes.